# Corda Walking the Chain in finalityFlow

Tags: corda

In Corda, FinalityFlow:

1. Verifies transaction on initiator node
2. Notarizes transaction
3. Persists signedTransaction to vault of initiator
4. Distributes transaction to the `participants`

As per consensus, verification involves walking the chain.

I looked in FinalityFlow code. Where exactly does the walking-the-chain thing happen?

Do the notary and the `participants` also walk the chain? If yes, they check the signatures on each transaction in the chain, but where exactly in the code does it happen?

As per my understanding, `SendTransactionFlow` sends the transaction to the other parties on the `participants` lists. The other party also requests for attachments and transaction dependencies. Where actually does the walking-the-chain thing happen?

I need to understand walking the chain from a coding perspective.

Answer (score 2):

In `FinalityFlow`, the caller uses the following line to send the notarised transaction to the `participants` of all the states:

```
subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, notarised))
```

If we look at `AbstractNode.installCoreFlows`, we see that the node installs a default handler for `FinalityFlow` called `FinalityHandler`. `FinalityHandler` responds to the call to `SendTransactionFlow` in `FinalityFlow` by calling `ReceiveTransactionFlow`.

Inside `ReceiveTransactionFlow`, we can see that the node resolves the transaction's dependencies, verifies the transaction and checks its signatures:

```
val stx = otherSideSession.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap {
    subFlow(ResolveTransactionsFlow(it, otherSideSession))
    it.verify(serviceHub, checkSufficientSignatures)
    it
}
```

As part of resolving the transaction's dependencies in `ResolveTransactionsFlow`, the node verifies each one and checks its signatures (by default, `verify` checks the signatures on the transaction):

```
result.forEach {
    it.verify(serviceHub)
    serviceHub.recordTransactions(StatesToRecord.NONE, listOf(it))
}
```

The notary will only walk the chain in this way if they are a validating notary.