# Implementing flow for Updation of state , do we have to use SendTransaction

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am trying to implement the flow for updation of state, so how do i pass the input state, and Can i ceate a seperate file for updation_flow and issue flow, and do i have to use SendtransactioFlow as a subflow?

I have passed in the input state to build the transaction, don,t know if it is correct please do verify.

code to add  the inputstate to the transaction in the transactionbuilder

```
// We create a transaction builder and add the components.
val hashasint: Int =  serviceHub.vaultService.hashCode()
val convertostring: String =   hashasint.toString()
val ourStateRef = StateRef(SecureHash.sha256(convertostring), 0)
val inputState: StateAndRef<KycState> = serviceHub.toStateAndRef(ourStateRef)
val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
        .addOutputState(outputState, KycContract.ID)
        .addCommand(command)
        .addInputState(inputState)
```

Code for implementing flow for state updation

```
val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

// Creating a session with the other party.
val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)   // i think here is where the actual link to other node starts
subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(otherPartySession,signedTx))

// Obtaining the counterparty's signature.
val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTx, listOf(otherPartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()))

// We finalise the transaction and then send it to the counterparty.
subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, otherPartySession))
```

Does the updation flow require the use of SendTransactionFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendTransactionFlow is called in FinalityFlow. No need to call separately. 
See in below link -

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt

Also refer SO - [Corda Walking the Chain in finalityFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314281/corda-walking-the-chain-in-finalityflow?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To update a state you need to fetch the state from the vault and use it as input state in your transaction builder. To fetch the state from the vault you could use vaultQuery. Here is an example:

```
List<StateAndRef<MyState>> myStateAndRefs = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(MyState.class).getStates();
```

You could use `QueryCriteria` if you want a filtered result. 
Refer here for more: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html

`SendTransactionFlow` isn't generally required to update the state. It would be required in cases where the initiated doesn't have the state he wants to update, where he would need to request for the input state from the counterparty. Since in this case, he would not have the transaction chain for the state in question he would have to request the same from the counterparty using `SendTransactionFlow`. This is required because the initiator would need to walk the transaction chain from the issuance of the state to the current state, in order to validate the authenticity of the state he has been provided.